# SectionIndexer with GridView in Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-3.0-honeycomb, adapter, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Is it possible to use a `SectionIndexer` with a `GridView` in Android? Fast scroll is working fine, and I'm using a custom adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`. The adapter is currently implementing `SectionIndexer` and seems to be identical to the examples shown online and on Stack Overflow. This made me think if it's even possible to do with a `GridView` and a custom adapter.

Comment: Of course it's possible, as long  as you're using a `Cursor` to sort your data.

Comment: I'm not using a Cursor. I've got it stored in an ArrayList, but I suppose I could change it to a Cursor. Got an example using a Cursor?

Comment: the best sample https://github.com/guoGavin/Andorid-StickyHeaderGridView

Comment: @MichellBak can you show me your example for sectionindexer in gridview.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static class YOUR_ADAPTER extends SimpleCursorAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

private AlphabetIndexer mIndexer;

 YOUR_ADAPTER (Context context, AlbumBrowserActivity currentactivity,
            int layout, Cursor cursor, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);

        getColumnIndices(cursor);
    } 

    private void getColumnIndices(Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor != null) {
            YOUR_COLUMN = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WHAT_YOU'RE_SORTING);

            if (mIndexer != null) {
                mIndexer.setCursor(cursor);
            } else {
                mIndexer = new AlphabetIndexer(cursor, YOUR_COLUMN, mResources.getString(
                        R.string.fast_scroll_alphabet));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        return mIndexer.getSections();
    }

    @Override   
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return mIndexer.getPositionForSection(section);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**fast_scroll_alphabet `String`**

```
<string name="fast_scroll_alphabet">\u0020ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</string>
```

That's a basic example, but there's not much more to it than that. Implementing `SectionIndexer` is pretty simple.

Comment: I was missing AlphabetIndexer :-)