# Gridview with alphabet indexer and alphabetically groupwise in android

Tags: android, android-gridview

IndexableGridView.java

```
public class IndexableGridView extends GridView {

private boolean mIsFastScrollEnabled = false;
private IndexGridScroller mScroller = null;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector = null;

public IndexableGridView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public IndexableGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public IndexableGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean isFastScrollEnabled() {
    return mIsFastScrollEnabled;
}

@Override
public void setFastScrollEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    mIsFastScrollEnabled = enabled;
    if (mIsFastScrollEnabled) {
        if (mScroller == null)
            mScroller = new IndexGridScroller(getContext(), this);
    } else {
        if (mScroller != null) {
            mScroller.hide();
            mScroller = null;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    // Overlay index bar
    if (mScroller != null)
        mScroller.draw(canvas);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Intercept ListView's touch event
    if (mScroller != null && mScroller.onTouchEvent(ev))
        return true;

    if (mGestureDetector == null) {
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                    float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                // If fling happens, index bar shows
                if (mScroller != null)
                    mScroller.show();
                return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
            }

        });
    }
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
}

@Override
public void setAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
    super.setAdapter(adapter);
    if (mScroller != null)
        mScroller.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    if (mScroller != null)
        mScroller.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer{

    private String mSections = "#ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
       private Context mContext;
       List<String> mItems;

       // Constructor
       public ImageAdapter(Context c, List<String> mItems) {
          mContext = c;
          this.mItems = mItems;
       }

       public int getCount() {
          return mItems.size();
       }

       public Object getItem(int position) {
          return mItems.get(position);
       }

       public long getItemId(int position) {
          return mItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
       }

       // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
          ImageView imageView;
          if (convertView == null) {
          imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
          imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
          imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
          imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
          } else {
          imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
          }

          imageView.setImageBitmap(getBitmapFromAsset("imgs", mItems.get(position)));
          return imageView;
       }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String[] sections = new String[mSections.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < mSections.length(); i++)

        sections[i] = String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i));

        return sections;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i = position; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < getCount(); j++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    // For numeric section
                    for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++) {
                        if (StringMatcher.match(String.valueOf(((String) getItem(j)).charAt(0)), String.valueOf(k)))
                            return j;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (StringMatcher.match(String.valueOf(((String) getItem(j)).charAt(0)), String.valueOf(mSections.charAt(i))))
                        return j;
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
private Bitmap getBitmapFromAsset(String folder, String strName)
{
    AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream istr = null;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        istr = assetManager.open(folder+"/"+strName);

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
    istr.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

i used above code for alphabet indexer on gridview. which is same as [this link](https://github.com/woozzu/IndexableListView).
i just change listview to gridview.. now my problem is its not showing me alphaindexer at right side.

listview indexer example:

[image]

i want to display data like below image:

[image]

Comment: Did you call `setFastScrollEnabled(true)` on your `IndexableGridView`?

Comment: @MikeM. yeah i tried, but i also want to display data in alphabetically groupwise..

Comment: @MikeM. i added image for that.

Comment: For that, make a pojo class with name string. Then pass that pojo to the `Comparator`. Compare name 1 with 2 and return the one that comes before.

Comment: @PsyDuck i want to make groupwise gridview..as you can see in image.

Comment: Yes, I replied only after seeing your post. When you sort the griditems according to the name, you come in a state where you can handle it when the 1st letter changes.

Comment: @PsyDuck as per your comment, you are giving answer for alphabetical order problem.

Comment: Yes, but that can tackle your problem. Add a validation to check the 1st letter change, when it does, add a view (blank line)

Comment: @PsyDuck can you tell me how can i display string in new row if 1st letter is change?

Comment: You can use the library if you dont want to code. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**For sorting the grid:**

Make a `pojo` class with name string. Then pass that `pojo` to the `Comparator`. Compare name 1 with 2 and return the one that comes before.

**For Grouping:**

Basically you want a header for grouping. Use this [library](http://tonicartos.github.io/StickyGridHeaders/) (Stickygridheaders) for that.

Comment: its really works..thanks a lot.. now i want alphabetical indexer in right side.

Comment: Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10389531/sectionindexer-with-gridview-in-android) for that.

Comment: its using cursor and SimpleCursorAdapter.. and i am using baseadapter.

Comment: When you implemented  alphabeticalIndexer with GridView, what happened exactly? Was the list shown at all? Show me the screenshot of that as well

Comment: not but my problem is at alphabeticalindexer object.its asking me for cursor..and i am not using any cursor here.

Comment: oh then give it a cursor. Add the Strings to a cursor and then use that cursor. Tutorial for [Adding Strings To Cursor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9917935/adding-rows-into-cursor-manually).

Comment: not at all.. i made gridview with group but didnt work that alphabetical indexer.

Comment: Did you follow my approach?

Comment: can you show me any example which convert string to cursor for indexer or any else..?

Comment: I gave you a link, did you go through that?

Comment: Yes, it's not doable. Did you try using same approach that you used to set it with the ListView?

Comment: we cant use same thing in gridview..and my gridview is also grouped. so i cant apply that logic.

Comment: @TusharGogna Iam big fan of yours. I hope I will get autograph from you in future  0.o